# react-native-paper nested List.Accordion height issue

Tags: list, react-native, nested, react-native-paper

I am trying to use a nested List.Accordion from react-native-paper to show items that have a category and a sub-category.  the top level accordion is the category, then when you open a category, you see a list of sub-categories that are also expandable to then show you the items in it.

This is what I have done:

```
return (
<List.Accordion
    key={`maincat-acc-${index.toString()}`}
    title='chevy'
    left={(props) => <List.Icon {...props} icon='' />}
    expanded={isExpandedSub(subCat)}
    onPress={() => toggleExpandedSub(subCat)}
>
    <List.Item 
        key={`cat-itm-${index.toString()}`} 
        title={SubCatAccordian(index, sub, subCategoryItems[index])} 
    />
</List.Accordion>
)
```

And the SubCatAccordian is a function that looks like:

```
const SubCatAccordian = (index, subCat, items) => {
        return (
            <SubListAccordion>
                <List.Accordion
                    style={{width: 400, marginLeft: -100, padding: 80, borderRadius: 8}}
                    key={`subcat-acc-${index.toString()}`}
                    title={subCat}
                    left={(props) => <List.Icon {...props} icon='' />}
                    expanded={isExpandedSub(subCat)}
                    onPress={() => toggleExpandedSub(subCat)}
                >
                    <List.Item
                        key={`subcat-itm-${index.toString()}`} 
                        title="A list item in the subcategory' 
                    />
                </List.Accordion>
            </SubListAccordion>
        )
    }
```

The functionallity of the accordions opening and closing for both the categories and subcategories works well.  The only issue is when I expand a sub-category, the items show, but when I click to close it, the items dissappear, but the height does not shrink back up.  I have two images to show what I mean.  Is there a way to get it to know to shrink the height when the nested accordion closes?  And if not, is there a better way to do a nested accordian than to use the react-native-paper List.Accordion? Or a better UI way to accomplish showing 3 levels of items?

[image: To start - before expanding a sub-category]

[image: After expanding a sub-category]

[image: After closing the sub-category - the height remains what it was when item showed instead of shrinking back down]